# How to deal with a process' message queue overflow?

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Elixir and I've never encountered this before issue before. I am curious as to what is the optimal or accepted way to deal with this kind of issue?

I `spawn` a process that receives data from a websocket and later `send`'s this data back to the parent. The parent runs a recursive `process()` function that `receive`'s data from the spawned process.

The `process` function matches the data and in the majority of cases runs a callback function. This callback function may be on the heavier side since it processes the data.

By dropping a lot of `Logger.info` statements I was able to find out that the spawned process receives data from the websocket and `send`'s this data to the parent process, *but* the parent process is not actually processing the mailbox.

I determined the parent process is alive using the `alive?/1` function and later I've checked the status of the mailbox using the `Process.info/1` function - it shows that the number of mailbox messages is growing (hundreds of messages).

My working solution is that instead of calling the callback in the `process` function, I `spawn` it, which I believe allows parent process to process its mailbox much quicker.

What are other, better ways to handle this situation?

```
def run(url, callback) do
    {domain, path} = parse_url(url)
    socket = Socket.Web.connect!(domain, path: path, secure: true)
    spawn_link(Project.WebsocketClient, :listen, [url, socket, self])

    process(callback)
end

def process(callback) do
    receive do
        {:ok, data} ->
            callback.(data)
            # spawn(fn -> callback.(data) end) - my fix.
        {:ping} ->
            Logger.info("Pong")
        {:error, _, url} ->
            run(url, callback)
    end
    process(callback)
end

defp recv(socket) do
    try do
        Socket.Web.recv!(socket)
    rescue
        e in RuntimeError -> {:error, e}
    end
end

def listen(url, socket, pid) do
    case recv(socket) do
        {:text, data} ->
            send(pid, {:ok, data})
        {:ping, _} ->
            Logger.info("Ping!")
            Socket.Web.send!(socket, {:pong, ""})
            send(pid, {:ping})
        {:error, e} ->
            Logger.warn("Websocket died because: #{inspect(e)}. Attempting to restart")
            send(pid, {:error, e, url})
            exit(:died)
    end
    listen(url, socket, pid)
end
```

Comment: As @tkowal points out this is a rather open-ended question.  I'm tempted to vote to close it for that reason but instead I'll just downvote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an open ended question, so I'll share my thoughts on the problem.

1. Why there are messages in the mailbox?

`receive` is selective. If someone else is sending messages to the process and they don't match any of those patterns, then messages might accumulate. It is always a good idea to log those messages or even crash the process:

```
receive do
  (...)
  other -> log_somewhere_or_crash(other)
end
```

2. If using `spawn` helped you, than probably the mailbox wasn't cluttered by wrong messages.

`spawn` isn't a bad idea, but you don't have control over number of processes, that are created. You might run out of memory, when you create millions of them. It might be good idea to use [poolboy](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy). You can define how many workers you want.

Before using a worker from the pool, you have to check it out. After his job is done, you have to check it back into the pool. If all workers are busy and you used the blocking API, than the *calling process will wait*. It will move the queue from 'process process' to 'listen process'.

3. Use `GenServer`.

You've reimplemented the `GenServer` behaviour with your `process` function. `GenServer` does exactly, what you want, but is usually easier to test and debug. You only specify callbacks. It can also be easily supervised.

4. Nothing will help you, when the system if overloaded.

If processing is heavy and your messages keep coming, they will be buffered somewhere. Now it is in the parent process. If you use `spawn`, they will be buffered in a number of processes waiting in the scheduler queue. If you slow down receiving messages from WebSocket, they will be stored in the TCP buffer, which can also overflow. That way, the sender will wait for the TCP window. If it generates messages in a separate thread, they will accumulate there.

It is good idea to have some kind of flow control mechanism, that informs the producer to slow down or drops the messages, that can't be processed.

There is a really great [blog post about it](http://ferd.ca/queues-don-t-fix-overload.html).